# Maintaining Formulae when Adding Rows/Columns

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm doing some excel sheet Python automation using openpyxl and I'm having an issue when I try to insert columns or rows into my sheet.

I'm modifying an existing excel sheet which has basic formula in it (i.e. `=F2-G2`) however when I insert a row or column before these cells, the formula do not adjust accordingly like they would if you would perform that action in excel.

For example, inserting a column before column `F` should change the formula to `=G2-H2` but instead it stays at `=F2-G2`...

Is there any way to work around this issue? I can't really iterate through all the cells and fix the formula because the file contains many columns with formula in them.

Comment: There are two main ways of dealing with your situation. First, if you're using a machine that has Excel installed on it, then you can automate Excel. A popular way to do this is with [xlwings](https://www.xlwings.org/). The second thing you can do is rebuild the file from scratch, including writing the appropriate formulas in the appropriate cells. This is the thing you said you "can't really" do, but actually you can; it just may be more annoying or tedious than you'd like.

Comment: Also, you can write code to build Excel formulas where you substitute cell addresses, which may be easier than what you're imagining, but I'm not sure because I don't know your programming abilities. If you have a lot of *different* formulas (not merely the same few formulas repeated in lots of places), then yes, it's just going to be plain tedious unless you can automate Excel itself.

Answer (score 1):

Easy, just iterate from your inserted row downward to the max row and change formulae's row number accordingly, below code is just a example:

```
#insert a new row after identified row   
ws.insert_rows(InsertedRowNo) 
#every time you insert a new row, you need to adjust all formulas row numbers after the new row.
for i in range (InsertedRowNo,ws.max_row):
    ws.cell(row=i,column=20).value='=HYPERLINK(VLOOKUP(TRIM(A{0}),dict!$A$2:$B$1001,2,0),A{0})'.format(i)
```

Comment: Can you explain how this works? Where is this .value from?

Answer (score 0):

openpyxl is a file format library and not an application like Excel and does not attempt to provide the same functionality. Translating formulae in cells that are moved should be possible with the library's tokeniser but this ignores any formulae that refer to the cells being moved on the same worksheet or in the same workbook.